# Does mariadb `NO_TABLE_OPTIONS`, `NO_FIELD_OPTIONS`, `NO_KEY_OPTIONS SQL_MODE` change database content?

Tags: mariadb

From https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/show-create-table/,
I read

> MariaDB and MySQL-specific table options, column options, and index options are not included in the output of this statement if the NO_TABLE_OPTIONS, NO_FIELD_OPTIONS and NO_KEY_OPTIONS SQL_MODE flags are used.

I am not sure `NO_TABLE_OPTIONS`, `NO_FIELD_OPTIONS` and `NO_KEY_OPTIONS SQL_MODE` change only the grammar or change database content.
Is database `resource` from `mysqldump --NO_TABLE_OPTIONS --NO_FIELD_OPTIONS --NO_KEY_OPTIONS SQL_MODE --databases db1` same as `resource` from `mysqldump --databases db1`?

Answer (score 0):

`mysqldump` reads the database, but does not write to it.  It writes a text file you can look at.

You will find that those options remove certain settings relating character set, engine, auto_increment, etc.  These may make the generated SQL more compatible with some other database vendor or MySQL/MariaDB version.

The syntax I found was more like

```
mysqldump --compatible=no_table_options,no_field_options,no_key_options ...
```